# JDA Voice Activity Tracking

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda, lavaplayer

I want to track voice activity of my bot with JDA. I am using lavaplayer to stream audio to the voice channel, and I want bot to leave the channel after some time when it is inactive or there is no one except bot. I am new to the coding community and trying different things. Can you help me about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if there is anyone in the channel except the bot every time someone leaves the voice channel and start a timer or smth if this is the case.